# How many 6 digit numbers are there such that :

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many 6 digit numbers are there such that:

Digits of each number are from $1,2,3,4 ,5$
And  any digit that appears on the number ,appears at least twice.

Comment: Welcome to maths stack exchange! Can you share what ideas you've had, and any progress you've made? With this knowledge, people will be able to help you more effectively! :)

Comment: One approach might be to exclude the cases where at least one digit appears exactly once, using the principle of inclusion / exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Since any digit that appears on the number ,appears at least twice, we can say that number of appearing digits can be partitioned as $(6), (4,2), (3,3), (2,2,2)$ (This means we might have a digit that is repeated $6$ times or a digit repeated $4$ times and another digit repeated $2$ times, etc.). Then could you find how many numbers are there in each partition?

Comment: I did till here but was unable to find how many numbers ... kindly help in that

Comment: For example, can you answer in how many ways we can permute the digits of $111122$?

Comment: Yes it would be for this example 6!/4!2!

Comment: Yes it's correct. And in how many ways we can choose $2$ numbers out of $5$ for $(4,2)$ case?

Comment: Actually i am quiet new in it  so Maybe 6!/4!2!

Comment: Hmm, not really. Here, we are trying to change the digits without breaking the rule that there will be $4$ of one digit and $2$ of another. So, we can choose them with $\binom{5}{2}$ and since having four $1$'s and two $2$'s is different from having four $2$'s and two $1$'s, there are $2\binom{5}{2} = 20$ options for this case. So we should combine it with permutation of the digits to find how many such numbers in $(4,2)$ case in total.

Comment: Can you pls tell the solution plassssssssss

Comment: I am sorry but I think I have already given you hints more than enough. If you still have difficulties, I suggest you to grasp the logic behind combination, permutation, counting concepts.

Comment: Sir plsss i just want to crocc check my way cause i m not getting my answer correct